# Remove entries in Dired buffer without deleting actual underlying objects

Tags: elisp, dired, files

Is there a way to do this for both non-Elisp and Elisp? For Elisp, the only thing I can think of is to create a new Dired buffer from a new list of files, but is there a better way?

Note: I want to do this without external dependency.

Comment: Try out Dired-omit.

Comment: @Tu Do: you've posted a number of questions about `dired` that all specify that you don't want to introduce external dependencies.  That's fine and all, but I'm kind of curious why beyond the general "avoid external dependencies when you can" -- it seems like you might be reinventing a number of wheels.

Comment: @Dan I need it to contribute to Projectile, specifically [this feature](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/pull/484#comments). I finished the updating part. I don't want to introduce additional dependency when it's absolutely not necessary, because it will make it more difficult to review. Based on the answer, it seems there's no external package that satisfies my need: to add and update (add more or delete) Dired entries and still preserve state after updating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mark files (e.g. with <kbd>m</kbd>, but there are lots of marking functions), and then remove them with <kbd>k</kbd>.

Edit: The scenario in question appears to be a virtual dired buffer (or similar) using a custom source of file listings, and the problem is how, after modifications to the initial dired contents, to refresh the dired buffer without also reverting to the original contents (i.e. how to retain the modifications, even after reverting the dired buffer).

`dired-revert` (which re-runs the command to generate the original list of files) does remember a bunch of things already, but not killed lines (and one can easily argue that remembering killed lines is a bad idea), but you could provide a custom `revert-buffer-function` which did remember which lines had been killed.

I suspect if you're creating a dired buffer with custom contents, it's up to you to handle the `revert-buffer` case with similar custom logic.

Comment: This is close. But when refreshing, the entries still remain.

Comment: Well yes; that's because refreshing a dired buffer re-runs the original command to create the directory listing. So don't do that.

Comment: So, effectively we have to create a new Dired buffer? Or is there a way to replace that original command?

Comment: It's not clear to me what your use-case is, but perhaps you want `find-dired` rather than regular `dired`?

Comment: The use case is [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/pull/484#comments) (scroll down a bit). I can create a Dired buffer from arbitrary set of files, but now I want to update it. It is close now, but currently I have to kill buffer and recreate a new Dired buffer from the same name and having bizzare error.

Comment: You can use a virtual dired buffer, but you can't refresh those anyhow, so that's not ideal either. `dired-revert` *does* remember a bunch of things already, but not killed lines (and one can easily argue that remembering killed lines is a bad idea), but you could provide a custom `revert-buffer-function` which *did* remember which lines had been killed. I suspect if you're creating a dired buffer with custom contents, it's up to you to handle the `revert-buffer` case with similar custom logic.

Comment: I will use a custom command then. Please amend your answer with your comment on it's not possible to do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

[dired-narrow](https://github.com/Fuco1/dired-hacks/blob/master/dired-narrow.el)
may be a good place to look, both for a way to filter dired content
interactively and for exploring a method for implementing this in elisp.
To do this, it seems that dired-narrow adds the invisible property to
lines for files that don't match the search criteria and then
[deletes these lines](https://github.com/Fuco1/dired-hacks/blob/cdb22f2f082a6084dcbe979a56e40c86624f3d09/dired-narrow.el#L65-75).

Comment: I've edited my question. I don't want to have external dependency. I don't just want to narrow, but actually delete the entries without affecting actual objects the entries represent.